# Как защитить flash-видео на сайте от скачивания?

Tags: swf, flash, actionscript

Добрый день! У меня есть видео-ролики в формате swf, которые расположены на сайте: загружаются, воспроизводятся. Мне хотелось бы, чтобы их нельзя было скачать с сайта - на самом сайте такой возможности нет, но при желании - их можно взять их кэша браузера. Можно ли как-то защитить видео в формате swf от скачивания или максимально усложнить этот процесс?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Способ: Если у вас есть доступ к программному коду плеера - можно упаковать видео внутрь SWF файла. Грузить его в плеер, и потом изымать для проигрывания.

Еще способ: Отдавать файл через видео поток с помощью стрим ([FMS](http://www.adobe.com/products/flashmediaserver/), [Red5](http://www.wowza.com/), [Wowza](http://www.red5.org/)) сервера через RTMP/RTMFP, в плеере воспроизводить через NetConnection/NetStream.

Comment: Дополнительный вопрос: а что значит грузить в плеер, а потом изымать. Грузить понятно как, а изымать? И в чем смысл - я так понимаю при загрузке ролика в кэше браузера - файл уже появляется и его можно взять?